# How to store pandas dataframes with dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

I have big dataset and store it in pickle format (4 GB), and it tooks a lot of time to read file. I use pickle due to the fact that i have 2 columns with dictionaries and its necessary to keep this type after loading the file.

So my question is how to optimize reading, storaging and operating my data?

My dataframe looks like this 
and its necessary to save dict type after loading the data:

```
   0  1  2  3    4      5
0  1  2  3  4  {2:1}  {1:2}
1  2  4  6  8  {2:1}  {1:2}
```

Comment: Do you have any problem using pickle or do you want to know if there is any other, more efficient way?

Comment: Have you considered using parquet?

Comment: @Jano problem is that it tooks a lot of time to read large pickle file and i want to know how to do that i need in more efficient way

Comment: Are those dictionaries repeated often or is each one of them different for every row?

Comment: @Jano Different

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to convert your dictionaries to strings before saving and convert back after loading. This way you can save it as a csv text and avoid using pickle, which should speed up your task in this case.

```
import pandas as pd

# dummy df with dict types
ds = pd.Series([{1: 2}, {3: 4}])
df = pd.DataFrame(ds, columns=['a'])
print(df.iloc[0].values[0], type(df.iloc[0].values[0]))
>>> {1: 2} <class 'dict'>

# convert dict col to str objects
df['a'] = df['a'].apply(str)
print(df.iloc[0].values[0], type(df.iloc[0].values[0]))
>>> {1: 2} <class 'str'>

# save
df.to_csv('mydf.csv', index=False)

# read csv
df = pd.read_csv('mydf.csv')
print(df.iloc[0].values[0], type(df.iloc[0].values[0]))
>>> {1: 2} <class 'str'>

# convert str objects back to dicts
df['a'] = df['a'].apply(eval)
print(df.iloc[0].values[0], type(df.iloc[0].values[0]))
>>> {1: 2} <class 'dict'>
```